# AutoHotKey Script Continually Opening Program

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey

I'm trying to get my AutoHotKey Script to only open the selected program once and I don't know how to get it to do that. When I run it, it just loops over and over. I can't even close the processes as fast as they open.

Here is my current script:

```
RunWait, launcher.exe, J:\Steam\SteamApps\common\Starbound\win32\ pause
```

What can I do to make the script only open the target exe once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reason for that to happen. What program do you try to open?

What happens if you run an empty script with just that line in it?

```
Run, %A_WinDir%\system32\notepad.exe
```

You only need the second parameter (working directory), if your script is not in the same folder as the executable you are trying to run. But in this case you would need to pass the full path to the file (not only the file name) in the first parameter.

So it's either:

```
RunWait, J:\Steam\SteamApps\common\Starbound\win32\launcher.exe, J:\Steam\SteamApps\common\Starbound\win32\
```

or just

```
RunWait, launcher.exe
```

if you want to pass a command line parameter, you just attach it to the first parameter with a space.
Like this:

```
RunWait, J:\Steam\SteamApps\common\Starbound\win32\launcher.exe pause, J:\Steam\SteamApps\common\Starbound\win32\
```

Sometimes the parameters need a - or a / in front of them. so it might also be /pause or -pause...

Comment: Your script works just fine. I'm trying to create an executable script to open another executable; in this case a launcher for a game running through Steam.

Comment: The pause is, as I am completely guessing, supposed to pause the script so that it continues to run like an .exe without doing anything else. I need the executable batch file to remain open while my computer opens and runs the executable file that I'm opening with it.

Comment: Targeting the full path of the executable solved the problem precisely. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, if the pause is no command line parameter of your particular exe file, don't use it. The command RunWait causes the autohotkey script to freeze while the exe is running. So it doesn't close and doesn't execute any command followed by RunWait until you close your exe. I'm glad I was able to help you.